# Can not remote connect to postgres service

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, remote-server

I am running PostgreSQL on a Amazon Web Services ubuntu virtual machine. I have set the security groups to allow from 0.0.0.0, I have set up the hba_conf file to allow connections from

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

I have restarted the server and postgresql. I can not connect to the database.
When I try to connect from an ubuntu laptop I get

```
psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres@XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXX"
```

When I try to connect from PgAdmin on a Win 10 machine I get

```
Server Does Not Listen
```

What should be my next steps for resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was although I had switched from peer to md5 authentication I had not set an encrypted password for the postgres user.

```
$ su - postgres
$ psql
postgresql #= \password
```

Set a password that I was able to connect to.